# window.location... running last javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I just recently started working with java script and i'm learning how it works with html. I'm am basically creating a bot to buy clothes. In the main script I have a function that is going to find a item to buy for me on a website. The user inputs his or her item they want and they press the start button. It is suppose to then open the store and find the item on the website, add it to cart and buy it. My problem when you press the button it runs the function before changing the link even though it is written like this...

```
function doessomething(){
}

<input ... onclick"window.location='http://example.com'; doessomething()" />
```

I don't know how to fix this problem any help would be appreciated.

Comment: onclick=",,,,,.

Comment: Heads up, setting `location.href` starts a race with `doessomething()` and *may* redirect before `doessomething()` actualy does anything.  Also, `doessomething()` will act in the context of the initial page, not in the new context.  You *might* want to look at node or browser plugins as what you are looking to do is generally blocked by browsers for security reasons.